# Default initialize data members that are objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, object, syntax

Why do you have to initialize object data members in the constructor and you can't default initialize them like with primitive types? Is it possible to initialize them like with primitive types?

Here's an example:

```
class foo {
    int a;
public:
    foo(int _a) :a(_a) {};
};

class bar {
    string a = "asdf";//no error
    int num = 1;//no error
    foo x(1); //error, why?
    foo z;
public:
    bar(): z(1){}//no error
};
```

Comment: Because barring the literal, this is almost the same as a function definition, and to support both will make the syntax of the language more complicated. Why do that when you have two more readable ways to accomplish the same objective?

Comment: If you use an identifier instead of a literal – `foo x(baz);` – that has been a declaration of a member function since the beginning of time . Making whether it is a function or a variable depend on whether the `baz` in scope is a type or a variable is a path that leads to insanity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In-class initializers only work with the `operator=` syntax or with brace-initializer lists, not with the function style initialization. So

```
foo x{1};
```

instead of

```
foo x(1);
```

should do the trick.

In your case, you could also use

```
foo x = 1;
```

but that would break if `foo`'s constructor taking a single `int` was `explicit`.

Answer (score 2):

Permitting [*direct-initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) *in class-definition* would lead to difficulties in distinguishing from function declarations:

Consider:

```
struct k;

struct foo { foo(int x = 1){} };

class toto
{
static constexpr int k = 1;
foo x(1); // hm might be ok...
foo y(); // hm ... NOK , what y is ? an object or a function declaration?!?!
foo z(k); // problem .... this seems a fucntion definition?!!!
foo z{k}; // clear it is not a function definition
};
```

The proper way to do this is either:

```
foo f= 1;
```

or

```
foo f{1};
```

or

```
foo f = {1};
```